# What is the notation of length of vector?

Tags: notation, vectors

I am looking for a symbol to express the length of a vector or table,
For example we have a vector V, len(V)==5 ( for example).
How can I represent it by a symbol ?

Comment: You can represent it by any symbol you want, so long as you make what you are doing clear to the reader.

Comment: What do you mean by the length of a vector?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, in mathematics we use $\|v\|$ for length (as in the length of a line segment, for example).

In programming, length typically stands for the number of dimensions, so if $V$ is some vector space, $\dim V$ denotes its dimension (number of linearly independent directions). So $\dim \mathbb{R^n} = n$.

I suppose you could define your own symbol, e.g. $(v)$ to mean the number of dimensions in the space $v$ comes from, which would be analogous to your notion of length, I think. However, I've not seen such a symbol directly.

Another close match is that if $S$ is a set, $|S|$ denotes its cardinality, i.e. number of elements of $S$. In your case, however, $v$ is less of a set and more of a tuple...